# Timing Sort functions

Tags: python

```
import time

def timeSort(sortfn, L):
   t1 = time.time()
   sortfn(L)
   t2 = time.time()
   return (t2 - t1)

# try, e.g.,
# l = mixup(list(range(4000)))
# timeAllSorts(l)
def timeAllSorts(L):

    Lcopy = L[:]
    sTime = timeSort(selectionSort, Lcopy)
    Lcopy = L[:]
    iTime = timeSort(insertionSort, Lcopy)
    Lcopy = L[:]
    mTime = timeSort(mergeSort, Lcopy)
    Lcopy = L[:]
    biTime = timeSort(builtinSort, Lcopy)
    Lcopy = L[:]
    qTime = timeSort(quicksort, Lcopy)

   print("{}\t sel: {:.2f}\t ins: {:.2f}\t merge: {:.2f}\t builtin: {:.2f}\t quick:{:.2f}".format(len(L), sTime, iTime, mTime, biTime,qTime))
```

I have multiple sorting functions, I could not fit all them in the code but for example my quicksort():

```
import random
def quicksort(L):
    if len(L)<2: return L
    pivot_element = random.choice(L)
    small = [i for i in L if i< pivot_element]
    medium = [i for i in L if i==pivot_element]
    large = [i for i in L if i> pivot_element]
    return quicksort(small) + medium + quicksort(large)
```

When I run the timeAllSorts function it returns a runtime of 0.00 for every function and I am not sure why this happens. Maybe with my print statement?

```
>>> timeAllSorts([12,5,13,8,9,65])
6    sel: 0.00   ins: 0.00   merge: 0.00     builtin: 0.00   quick:0.00
```

Comment: You've specified two digits after the decimal point with `{:.2f}`. To two digits after the decimal point, these sorts take 0.00 seconds to sort the tiny input.

Answer (score 2):

Sorting 5 integers will take no time for even the worst sorting algorithm. To properly test you will need several hundred or even thousand items.

For example, [testing with 8000 items shows that the `sorted` inbuilt is still "0 seconds", while quicksort is "0.05" seconds](https://ideone.com/lUJD0T)

```
import time

def timeSort(sortfn, L):
   t1 = time.time()
   sortfn(L)
   t2 = time.time()
   print t2-t1
   return (t2 - t1)

# try, e.g.,
# l = mixup(list(range(4000)))
# timeAllSorts(l)

import random
def quicksort(L):
    if len(L)<2: return L
    pivot_element = random.choice(L)
    small = [i for i in L if i< pivot_element]
    medium = [i for i in L if i==pivot_element]
    large = [i for i in L if i> pivot_element]
    return quicksort(small) + medium + quicksort(large)

def timeAllSorts(L):

    Lcopy = L[:]
    qTime = timeSort(quicksort, Lcopy)
    sTime = timeSort(sorted, Lcopy)

    print("{}\t sel:{:.2f} quick:{:.2f}".format(len(L),sTime, qTime))

l = list(range(8000,1,-1))
timeAllSorts(l)
```

> ```
> 7999   sel:0.00 quick:0.05
> ```

Answer (score 0):

As user2357112 said, you have specified quick:{:.2f}, which is insufficient resolution to show anything but 0.  The first significant digit occurs only after four zeros (on my machine).  So try something like quick:{:.10f}.